# Python, handling Py_buildValue in python code

Tags: python, c

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to call a C function from python and want to receive two variables. To keep it simple I display my sample code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

PyObject* foo(char *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return Py_BuildValue("ii", 2, 2);

}
```

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib1.so')
>>> d = lib.foo('hello')
hello
>>> d
43128392
```

Why it's not printing correct values?

Compilation command: 
gcc -c -IC:\Python26\include 1.c -o 1.o

gcc  -shared -Wl,-soname,lib1.so -o lib1.so 1.o -LC:\Python26\libs -LC:\Python26\PCbuild -lpython26

Comment: why do you call it as a C function instead of importing it as a C extension module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ctypes` expect functions to return `int` and you're returning an object. You need to change the return of your function:

```
from ctypes import cdll, py_object
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib1.so')

d = lib.foo('hello')
print d                     # prints address of object

lib.foo.restype = py_object # change the result type
d = lib.foo('hello')
print d                     # prints (2, 2) as expected
```

You can find more information here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Comment: If it's the answer you were looking for, you may want to accept it ;)